# I am trying to connect GIT local repository with WIndows using ssh. I generated ssh key and stored in C drive but confused with the furthur steps

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I am trying to connect GIT local repository with WIndows using ssh. I generated ssh key and stored in C:\Users\mymachine.ssh but dont know the furthur steps. Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to generate your key in a folder named `.ssh` `/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa` (maybe its different on windows?)
2. Then you can copy your public key with `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`to your Github Account or with `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<hostname> 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys` you can copy your public key to another machine

Comment: I have done this step. Should the keys be copied to the GIT folder? I need furthur info as to how git will use ssh keys. I am new to GIT and dont have much knowledge on it.

Comment: As I wrote, copy the public key to your github, gitlab, bitbucket account or if you don't work with these services, you have to copy the key to the authorized_keys file on the server. You don't need to copy the key to the Git folder.